# Redirecting full path on existing domain to same path on subdomain using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, redirect

I am trying to redirect a path from an existing domain to the same path on a new subdomain and after trying many different options am still struggling to get it to resolve as needed. Here's an example.

I need to redirect any link using...

```
domain.com/clients/existing/multi/folder/path/file.zip
```

to...

```
clients.domain.com/clients/same/multi/folder/path/file.zip
```

Essentially, the goal here is to redirect any path in the 'clients' folder on the original domain to the same path in the 'clients' folder on the new subdomain.

At this time I am currently using this code. It's the latest I've tested, but with no success. Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your rule, you are matching a subdomain of the first domain. This should not be so (as per your question details). Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(clients)/.*$ http://$1.domain.com/$0 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```